# Programmatically add button and add close command in one line

Tags: c#, wpf, events, button

I want to create a new window and add a button to close it when clicked.
I'd like to have all the close command in one line without having to use an event handler in another routine.

Something like

```
var mw= new MyWindow();
Button bt = new Button();
bt.Content = "OK";
bt.Click = ???? mw.close
```

withouth having to do

```
bt.Click += Bt_Click;
}
var mw= new MyWindow();<---- global
private void Bt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  mw.Close();
}
```

by doing so I can keep my window Local without having to make it global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using a lambda like:

```
bt.Click += (sender, args) => mw.Close();
```